# azure api azure internal server error 500

Tags: c#, azure-api-management

I create an API for the first time and when I publish in azure, for testing and learning, every time I test the GET function I receive this

HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error

content-length: 0
date: Sat, 27 Mar 2021 02:23:57 GMT
ocp-apim-apiid: gameslibrary
ocp-apim-operationid: get-jogos-getid-id
ocp-apim-subscriptionid: master
ocp-apim-trace-location: https://apimstpybsp1axvzdf4aexhk.blob.core.windows.net/apiinspectorcontainer/tQH3FZsFKaVfPQRaAAUemQ2-18?sv=2019-07-07&sr=b&sig=Kw0KsFABS4Z7ZJhyHNsEchsglcH5txW1yqNY0hx%2Be8o%3D&se=2021-03-28T02%3A23%3A55Z&sp=r&traceId=a1d01c85dd4e4070ba332731a91aa05d
vary: Origin
x-powered-by: ASP.NET

I have no idea where's the problem, can anyone pls help me
OBS: in the localhost works, only at azure no

Comment: Did you try to use application insights to get your logs

Comment: at the localhost?

Comment: You have problem at azure or at localhost?

Comment: at azure, localhost works fine

Comment: So add application insights

Comment: No answers in question please. I have edited/rolledback your answer out of the question. Please write an answer instead.

Comment: Please, don't post trace inspector links, they do contain at least subscription keys used to make a call. If call was made from Azure Portal master subscription key would be in there. I highly recommend that you rotate it, operation can be performed from APIM Subscriptions page in Azure Portal.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, without looking at the trace, it's hard to say, what went wrong. But in your particular case 500 response was returned by backend.

When test call is made from Azure Portal (or with trace headers), response will contain ocp-apim-trace-location header, it will point to trace of performed call. Researching this trace usually answers questions where error was produced. In your case you should be able to see "backend", it should contain information about what request was made to your backend and what response was received.

Comment: This was the pointer I needed. For me, I was getting a 500, because the 'Web service URL' was not set correctly. Looking at the Trace > Backend detailed the URL was not set.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't click that link (as far as I know they're often meant to be confidential), but have you tried checking allowed IP addresses?

Also (update):

Check that wherever you're calling the API from has a http tunnel allowed out. This depends on the exact nature of the place you're deploying your custom code to. You haven't told us.

Comment: i didn't change any config at azure, just don't work, btw that is the URL i receive from azure https://gameslibr.azure-api.net/jgs/Jogos/GetID/1

Comment: and where i can check the allowed ip?

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Are you talking about visual studio? I used Visual studio to make the code and publish from there

Comment: sorry, i didnt understand, for what reason i publish?

Comment: " used Visual studio to make the code and publish from there "
Publish your code what to? An Azure App? A virtual machine? Take the time to explain your process clearly and in detail.

Comment: ok, I create an API from visual studio and publish to an azure API management service, when I test from there, because I just want to test the API as public, I receive an internal server error

Comment: That would have been very helpful in the question. Update your question to include all this detail.